# Cannot find the exact eror sometimes showing Adapter not attached sometimes cannot find memetrack

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, android-recyclerview, splash-screen

My code -> https://github.com/rakshityadav07/Android/tree/master/NewsApp

```
2020-05-29 17:28:23.017 1666-1707/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2020-05-29 17:28:43.244 20988-20988/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.newsapp, PID: 20988
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(174571416bytes) bitmap.
        at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:229)
        at android.view.RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(RecordingCanvas.java:97)
        at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:529)
        at com.squareup.picasso.PicassoDrawable.draw(PicassoDrawable.java:109)
        at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1367)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19123)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18073)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19126)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18073)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
   2020-05-29 17:28:44.096 1418-1418/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 1418: eglCreateSyncKHR(2058): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
```

2020-05-29 17:28:44.245 1499-4313/? E/AudioFlinger: openRecord() permission denied: recording not allowed
2020-05-29 18:06:00.351 2455-16937/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -1
2020-05-29 18:06:00.354 2455-16937/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -1.
2020-05-29 18:06:00.354 2455-16937/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
2020-05-29 18:06:00.355 2455-16937/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
2020-05-29 18:06:01.886 1502-1526/? E/installd: Failed to delete /data/app/vmdl2115498749.tmp: No such file or directory
2020-05-29 18:06:02.157 2359-2680/com.google.android.gms E/GmsClient: unable to connect to service: com.google.android.gms.auth.key.retrieval.service.START on com.google.android.gms
2020-05-29 18:06:02.482 2455-21400/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox E/ContentStoreEUAS: Failed to commit the deferred actions
2020-05-29 18:06:02.725 1418-1467/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
2020-05-29 18:06:03.508 2146-18485/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/ctxmgr: [AppIntervalImpl] closeInterval: ongoing [CONTEXT service_id=47 ]
2020-05-29 18:06:06.915 21385-21385/com.example.newsapp E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
2020-05-29 18:06:07.599 21385-21385/com.example.newsapp E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
    2020-05-29 18:06:10.890 21385-21385/com.example.newsapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.newsapp, PID: 21385
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(174571416bytes) bitmap.
            at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:229)
            at android.view.RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(RecordingCanvas.java:97)
            at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:529)
            at com.squareup.picasso.PicassoDrawable.draw(PicassoDrawable.java:109)
            at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1367)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19123)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18073)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19126)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18073)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
            at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.drawChild(RecyclerView.java:5030)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19126)
            at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.draw(RecyclerView.java:4429)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18073)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19126)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18073)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)
            at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
            at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)

```
2020-05-29 18:06:10.891 21385-21385/com.example.newsapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6733)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

2020-05-29 18:06:35.980 1666-1707/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2020-05-29 18:06:36.197 1666-1707/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2020-05-29 18:06:53.733 1666-1707/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2020-05-29 18:06:53.783 1666-1707/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2020-05-29 18:06:53.813 1666-1707/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2020-05-29 18:06:53.839 1666-1707/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2020-05-29 18:08:16.030 2146-17369/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/WakeLock: GCM_HB_ALARM release without a matched acquire!
2020-05-29 18:08:26.188 1666-1707/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2020-05-29 18:08:26.261 1666-1711/system_process E/BatteryStatsService: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
2020-05-29 18:08:59.670 1418-1465/? E/hw-IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (1 threads) starved for 386 ms
2020-05-29 18:09:04.285 1418-1465/? E/hw-IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (1 threads) starved for 223 ms
2020-05-29 18:09:15.159 21451-21451/com.example.newsapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.newsapp, PID: 21451
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(174571416bytes) bitmap.
        at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:229)
        at android.view.RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(RecordingCanvas.java:97)
        at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:529)
        at com.squareup.picasso.PicassoDrawable.draw(PicassoDrawable.java:100)
        at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1367)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19123)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18073)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19126)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18073)
```